# How to concert dictionary JSON representation to normal JSON?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Next string have type: `<type 'dict'>`

```
response = vars(reader.country(tempIP))
```

If I am printing it, I am getting next:
`{'raw': {'traits': {'ip_address': '8.35.60.229'}, u'country': {u'geoname_id': 6252001, u'iso_code': u'US', u'names': {u'ru': u'\u0421\u0428\u0410', u'fr': u'\xc9tats-Unis', u'en': u'United States', u'de': u'USA', u'zh-CN': u'\u7f8e\u56fd', u'pt-BR': u'Estados Unidos', u'ja': u'\u30a2\u30e1\u30ea\u30ab\u5408\u8846\u56fd', u'es': u'Estados Unidos'}}, u'continent': {u'geoname_id': 6255149, u'code': u'NA'}, u'registered_country': {u'geoname_id': 6252001, u'iso_code': u'US', u'names': {u'ru': u'\u0421\u0428\u0410', u'fr': u'\xc9tats-Unis', u'en': u'United States', u'de': u'USA', u'zh-CN': u'\u7f8e\u56fd', u'pt-BR': u'Estados Unidos', u'ja': u'\u30a2\u30e1\u30ea\u30ab\u5408\u8846\u56fd', u'es': u'Estados Unidos'}}}, 'traits': geoip2.records.Traits(connection_type=None, domain=None, autonomous_system_number=None, autonomous_system_organization=None, isp=None, user_type=None, is_legitimate_proxy=False, organization=None, ip_address='8.35.60.229', is_anonymous_proxy=False, is_satellite_provider=False), 'country': geoip2.records.Country(geoname_id=6252001, iso_code=u'US', confidence=None, _locales='r', names={u'ru': u'\u0421\u0428\u0410', u'fr': u'\xc9tats-Unis', u'en': u'United States', u'de': u'USA', u'zh-CN': u'\u7f8e\u56fd', u'pt-BR': u'Estados Unidos', u'ja': u'\u30a2\u30e1\u30ea\u30ab\u5408\u8846\u56fd', u'es': u'Estados Unidos'}), 'represented_country': geoip2.records.RepresentedCountry(geoname_id=None, confidence=None, _locales='r', names={}, iso_code=None, type=None), 'registered_country': geoip2.records.Country(geoname_id=6252001, iso_code=u'US', confidence=None, _locales='r', names={u'ru': u'\u0421\u0428\u0410', u'fr': u'\xc9tats-Unis', u'en': u'United States', u'de': u'USA', u'zh-CN': u'\u7f8e\u56fd', u'pt-BR': u'Estados Unidos', u'ja': u'\u30a2\u30e1\u30ea\u30ab\u5408\u8846\u56fd', u'es': u'Estados Unidos'}), '_locales': 'r', 'maxmind': geoip2.records.MaxMind(queries_remaining=None), 'continent': geoip2.records.Continent(geoname_id=6255149, code=u'NA', _locales='r')}`

it's not valid JSON. Is there any way to make it's normal?

Answer (score 0):

you want to

`import json`

and then

`print json.dumps(response)`

but you are likely to run into an issue with your `geoip2` values - simplest thing is to delete those keys before you try to print.